# Oracle SQL Auto Generated Identity Primary Key

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle's SQLDeveloper and trying to create some tables. 
My goal is to create a simple table, for example, with an auto-generated id together with a description.

```
CREATE TABLE xpto (
id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm getting:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02000: missing ( keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need Oracle 12.1 for that. Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Oracle IDE 4.1.5.21.78

Comment: That's the version of your SQL client, **not** the version of your Oracle **server**

Comment: EDIT: 11.2.0.1.0

Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Identity columns is a feature supported by Oracle from version 12c.
In Oracle 11 it does not work, you must use a sequence and a trigger, in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE xpto (
id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE xpto_seq;

set define off
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER xpto_id 
BEFORE INSERT ON xpto 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( new.id IS NULL )
BEGIN
   :new.id := xpto_seq.nextval;
END;
/
```