# How to import data from AWS S3 to table with auto generated identity primary key without including ID column in CSV file?

Tags: oracle, amazon-s3, data-import

I have following table

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
   C_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   C_NUMBER NUMBER NOT NULL,
   C_TEXT VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
   C_DATE DATE NOT NULL
)
```

and CSV file stored in **AWS S3 bucket**

```
C_NUMBER;C_TEXT;C_DATE;
17358;TKPBGZ;2022-12-15;
39630;FCFGZT;2020-08-01;
26458;NIWRGD;2020-05-19;
32561;JENFWF;2022-06-23;
...
```

Data load to mentioned table fails despite the fact `C_ID` should be generated by default. Is there any other option than adding `C_ID` column to the CSV file?

Comment: I tried to create a sequence and a trigger as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43336923/12199832) but it also doesn't work.

Comment: How are you trying to do the data load? Can you please share the same steps + exactly how the sequence&trigger also didn’t *work*?